# Could not find WebView element in Android Editor Library

Tags: java, android, automation, appium

Android Application team are using this [GitHub](https://github.com/wasabeef/richeditor-android) editor library in project. When I am trying to find element in appium but it could not recognize.

```
WebElement DisText =driver.findElement(By.id("editor"));
DisText.clear();
DisText.sendKeys("Ashwini");
```

**editor** is **android:id** given in Android code and I am passing "Ashwini" as text in editor.

Thanks in Advance.

**Update**:

Exception :

```
 org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: An element could not be located on the page using the given search parameters. (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
Command duration or timeout: 15.04 seconds
For documentation on this error, please visit: http://seleniumhq.org/exceptions/no_such_element.html
Build info: version: '3.4.0', revision: 'unknown', time: 'unknown'
System info: host: 'IVL-WS18', ip: '192.168.6.28', os.name: 'Windows 7', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '6.1', java.version: '1.8.0_161'
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver
Capabilities [{appPackage=com.xxxxxx.xxxcc, appActivity=com.xxxxxx.xxxcc.features.splash.SplashActivity, noReset=true, automationName=UiAutomator2, javascriptEnabled=true, udid=33000a542eebb30f, platformName=Android, deviceName=Galaxy On8, fullReset=false, platform=ANY}]
Session ID: e10311e5-0f0d-4a93-8a24-3a8e03e74529
*** Element info: {Using=id, value=editor}
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.createThrowable(ErrorHandler.java:215)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.throwIfResponseFailed(ErrorHandler.java:167)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:671)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.findElement(RemoteWebDriver.java:410)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.findElementById(RemoteWebDriver.java:453)
    at org.openqa.selenium.By$ById.findElement(By.java:218)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.findElement(RemoteWebDriver.java:402)
    at com.first.time.NoteToMc.TestWithoutReset(NoteToMc.java:56)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:124)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeMethod(Invoker.java:580)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethod(Invoker.java:716)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethods(Invoker.java:988)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.invokeTestMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:125)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:109)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.privateRun(TestRunner.java:648)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:505)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:455)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:450)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:415)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:364)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:52)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:84)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1208)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1137)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuites(TestNG.java:1049)
    at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1017)
    at org.testng.remote.AbstractRemoteTestNG.run(AbstractRemoteTestNG.java:114)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.initAndRun(RemoteTestNG.java:251)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.main(RemoteTestNG.java:77)
```

Attributes attached in the screenshot 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KyXRP.jpg)

Comment: Kindly share the exception that you are getting aldo the webelement attributes screenshot

Comment: I have updated the question

Comment: use findelementByid(""); Also confirm that u r using AndroidDriver instead of WebDriver. And check whether the id=editor is unique.

Comment: please share full code.

Answer (score 0):

You can try another type of android locator called uiAutomator:

1. Try the following in you appium inspector with **"uiAutomator"** instead of "id":

   `new UiSelector().className("android.view.View").instance(0)`
2. `AndroidElement e = ((AndroidDriver)driver).findElementByAndroidUIAutomator("new UiSelector().className("android.view.View").instance(0)");`

Hope this can help.

For more uiAutomator usages, you can check:
[UiSelector](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/test/uiautomator/UiSelector)